# How Can I Create Password Field In SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-field-types, password

I had a problem with SharePoint data Types.

when I create a single line text column, type of this column is text and when I want to use this column as password field, There is no option change type to the password.

and characters are shown normal Instead of '*****'

I also use InfoPath, But my problem is not solved

please say me how can I change this text Type to Password in SharePoint forms.

Type = text

---

| 123456451256 |

---

Type = Password

---

| ************** |

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to create a custom field type and following link provides in detail how to create a custom field type

> [MSDN - How to create a custom field type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862248.aspx)
>
> This topic provides an overview of the process of creating a custom
>   field type and defining how it renders on list views and on the
>   Display, New, and Edit forms.
>
> For a concrete example of creating a custom field and defining its
>   rendering, see [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Field Type.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861799.aspx)
>
> The alternative 'hacky but pragmatic way' is as Vladi suggests using
>   some Javascript (perhaps in a CEWP) to modify the pages HTML.
>
> You would want to find the field INPUT tag and change the type to
>   Password (this will then use * instead of chars).
>
> This post gives you an [walkthrough of opening up a New/Edit.asp form
>   in edit mode, adding a CEWP that contains JavaScript and modifying the
>   page](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/09/setting-default-duration-for-new-calender-events/). Its not exactly what you want but will get you started.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301631/how-to-make-a-column-type-in-sharepoint-list-behave-as-a-password-field)

OR if you want use a ready-made you can get it from codeplex

http://wssfields.codeplex.com/releases/view/31155